# Creating array with ng-model when checkbox selection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs and want to create the model array when i click the checkbox and below is my code..

```
$scope.selectedAlbumSongs = [{
    'name': 'song1',
        'url': 'http://test/song1.mp3'
}, {
    'name': 'song2',
        'url': 'http://test/song2.mp3'
}, {
    'name': 'song3',
        'url': 'http://test/song3.mp3'
}];
$scope.playList = {};
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Select songs to play</legend>
    <label ng-repeat="song in selectedAlbumSongs">
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{song.url}}" id="{{song.name}}" ng-model="playList[song.url]">
        <label for="{{song.name}}">{{song.name}}</label>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

The above code updating the playList as shown below when i click the checkbox

```
{
    "http://test/test1.mp3": true,
    "http://test/test2.mp32": true,
    "http://test/test3.mp3": false
}
```

But I want to create the ng-model in the below format, and remove the object when the checkbox is unchecked (for ex. if the uncheck the song3, the song3 object removed from the array). Can you tell me how can write this logic?

Expected:

```
[{
    name: "song1",
    url: "http://test/song1.mp3"
}, {
    name: "song2",
    url: "http://test/song2.mp3"
}]
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$scope.selectedAlbumSongs = [ { 'name': 'song1', 'url': 'http://test/song1.mp3' }, { 'name': 'song2', 'url': 'http://test/song2.mp3' }, {'name': 'song3', 'url': 'http://test/song3.mp3' }];

$scope.selectedSongs = function () {
    $scope.playList = $filter('filter')($scope.selectedAlbumSongs, {checked: true});
}
```

Then, simple call selectedSongs() when the selection is changed:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{song.url}}" id="{{song.name}}" ng-model="song.checked" ng-change="selectedSongs()">
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wTZYn/)

Comment: Hi @ehlers that is an excellent solution. Can you tell me how I can do the same think when I have dynamic ngModels for checkboxes inside a ngRepeat? For example in a case like this where I have a `song.id` as ngmodel for each checkbox: `<input type="checkbox" name="{{song.url}}" id="{{song.name}}" ng-model="song.id" ng-change="selectedSongs()">`. I noticed the above code only works when having `ng-model="song.checked"`. But when I have a dynamic ngmodel `"song.id"`, it doesnt work. Any workaround in that case plz?